# Wireless not working on Toshiba S55-A5294, RTL8188EE

Tags: wireless, drivers

Out of the box wifi continuously prompts for password and never connects.

(Sorry, I had to leave the 'h' off of the 'http' because I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links)

Model:
`Toshiba S55-A5294`

Card:

```
lspci -v | grep -i wireless

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless 
Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Ubuntu and Kernel versions tried:

```
Ubuntu 13.10 3.11.0-12-generic
Ubuntu 13.10 3.11.0-12-generic
```

I have tried several things:

**1)** Compiling and using RealTek drivers per: ttp://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026

***Result:*** 
Errors found in ttp://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183804.

**2)** Drivers and instructions provided by ttp://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281

**Result:**
Wifi continuously prompts for password and never connects.

**3)** Using the modified drivers per instructions on https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver recommended by ***bb1netusaf2004*** on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183804. I reset the modules (drivers) to the original kernal ones before this step.

**Result:** Now I can connect to my wifi, but nothing loads all requests appear to timeout (websites,router,ect..)

It seems so close to working now.

Prior to doing step 3:

```
lsmod | grep ^rtl

rtl8188ee              89614  0 
rtl_pci                26641  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                63229  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
```

after step 3:

```
lsmod | grep ^rtl 

rtl8188ee             138201  0 
rtlwifi               110108  1 rtl8188ee
```

So, I was wondering if missing the trl_pci module is the problem. I have tried

```
modprobe rtl_pci

FATAL: Module rtl_pci not found.
```

Step 3 does not appear to create this module, but it is still in the /lib/modules/[kernel name]/... directory.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get the wifi working for this card?

```
    *************** info trace ***************

    ***** uname -a *****

    Linux kyle-Satellite-S55-A 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    ***** lsb_release *****

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
    Release:    13.10
    Codename:   saucy

    ***** lspci *****

    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0181]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa40]
        Kernel driver in use: alx

    ***** lsusb *****

    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5606 IMC Networks 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ***** PCMCIA Card Info *****


    ***** iwconfig *****

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off


    ***** rfkill *****

    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

    ***** lsmod *****

    rtl8188ee              89614  0 
    rtl_pci                26641  1 rtl8188ee
    rtlwifi                63229  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
    mac80211              596969  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
    cfg80211              479757  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

    ***** nm-tool *****

    NetworkManager Tool

    State: connected (global)

    - Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
      Type:              802.11 WiFi
      Driver:            rtl8188ee
      State:             disconnected
      Default:           no
      HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

      Capabilities:

      Wireless Properties
        WEP Encryption:  yes
        WPA Encryption:  yes
        WPA2 Encryption: yes

      Wireless Access Points 
        nariya:          Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
        belkin.f9c.guests: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30
        BalzaFam:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
        Heather:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
        2WIRE826:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WEP
        HOME-3B12:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2
        belkin.f9c:      Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA2


    - Device: eth0  [Auto Ethernet] ------------------------------------------------
      Type:              Wired
      Driver:            alx
      State:             connected
      Default:           yes
      HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

      Capabilities:
        Carrier Detect:  yes
        Speed:           1000 Mb/s

      Wired Properties
        Carrier:         on

      IPv4 Settings:
        Address:         10.42.0.80
        Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
        Gateway:         10.42.0.1

        DNS:             10.42.0.1



    ***** NetworkManager.state *****
    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true
    WimaxEnabled=true

    ***** NetworkManager.conf *****

    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

    ***** interfaces *****

    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ***** iwlist *****

    wlan0     Scan completed :
              Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                        Channel:1
                        Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                        Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                        Encryption key:on
                        ESSID:""
                        Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                                  36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                        Mode:Master
                        Extra:tsf=000000c004dd8539
                        Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                        IE: Unknown: 0000
                        IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                        IE: Unknown: 030101
                        IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                        IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
              Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                        Channel:1
                        Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                        Quality=70/70  Signal level=-18 dBm  
                        Encryption key:on
                        ESSID:"nariya"
                        Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                                  36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                        Mode:Master
                        Extra:tsf=000000c004dc85d0
                        Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                        IE: Unknown: 00066E6172697961
                        IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                        IE: Unknown: 030101
                        IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                        IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                            Group Cipher : TKIP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                        IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                        IE: WPA Version 1
                            Group Cipher : TKIP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
              Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                        Channel:7
                        Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                        Quality=70/70  Signal level=27 dBm  
                        Encryption key:on
                        ESSID:"HOME-3B12"
                        Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                                  18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                        Mode:Master
                        Extra:tsf=0000023b7584b8b0
                        Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                        IE: Unknown: 0009484F4D452D33423132
                        IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                        IE: Unknown: 030107
                        IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                        IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060
                        IE: Unknown: 2D1A0C0017FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                        IE: Unknown: 3D1607030700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                        IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                        IE: WPA Version 1
                            Group Cipher : TKIP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                        IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                            Group Cipher : TKIP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                        IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                        IE: Unknown: 0B05060018127A
                        IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                        IE: Unknown: DD07000C4303000000
                        IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B10
                        IE: Unknown: DD870050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102880288028801880A880001DD2603B1010210005415252495310230006544738363247102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F204000110110012415252495320544738363220526F7574657210080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
              Cell 04 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                        Channel:7
                        Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                        Quality=70/70  Signal level=-18 dBm  
                        Encryption key:on
                        ESSID:""
                        Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                                  18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                        Mode:Master
                        Extra:tsf=0000023b75863b69
                        Extra: Last beacon: 320ms ago
                        IE: Unknown: 0000
                        IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                        IE: Unknown: 030107
                        IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060
                        IE: Unknown: 070C55532001010F0209110B010F
                        IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                        IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                        IE: Unknown: 2D1A0C0017FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                        IE: Unknown: 3D1607030700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                        IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                        IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                            Group Cipher : CCMP
                            Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                            Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                        IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                        IE: Unknown: 0B05060018127A
                        IE: Unknown: DD07000C4303000000
              Cell 05 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                        Channel:11
                        Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                        Quality=70/70  Signal level=16 dBm  
                        Encryption key:on
                        ESSID:"belkin.f9c"
                        Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                                  24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                        Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                        Mode:Master
                        Extra:tsf=00000007b9d76318
                        Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago


   IE: Unknown: 000A62656C6B696E2E663963
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD930050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010A29E27421BFEFB4C6B0106D76F61CF101021000642656C6B696E1023000A46394B313131372076311024000776312E302E303010420004323034301054000800060050F20400011011001C42656C6B696E20414339303020576972656C65737320526F75746572100800020004103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201000C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101880003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=20 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"belkin.f9c.guests"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000007b9d82a04
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 001162656C6B696E2E6639632E677565737473
                    IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0106
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1ABC191BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B001700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200000C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101880003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00


***** resolv.conf *****

nameserver 127.0.1.1

***** blacklist *****

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

***** modinfo *****

filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         zhiyuan_yang    <zhiyuan_yang@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     3DC80AFBD6DC9B10E085376
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008179sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-12-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     69021F8FC8BF76DE7C8DD9C
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-12-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     E94C1FCAB8071D430AC01C6
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-12-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 


***** udev rules *****

# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8179 (rtl8188ee)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

***** dmesg *****

[   23.595159] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[   23.798541] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   23.798692] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   26.522873] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   61.694964] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   63.618018] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   63.637760] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   63.735593] wlan0: authenticated
[   63.737619] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   63.809503] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=7)
[   63.809674] wlan0: associated
[   63.809700] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   73.722206] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address removed> lost
[   78.189556] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   78.209478] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   78.313237] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
[   78.417377] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
[   78.521571] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
[   79.479341] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   79.499204] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   79.593071] wlan0: authenticated
[   79.595030] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   79.695423] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=7)
[   79.695598] wlan0: associated
[   90.639140] wlan0: disassociating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[   90.672951] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
[   93.651011] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[   93.670441] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   93.735967] wlan0: authenticated
[   93.738150] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[   93.840088] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=7)
[   93.840246] wlan0: associated
[  100.510648] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 15)
[  264.665782] rtl8188ee: rtl8188ee: FW Power Save off (module option)
[  264.665786] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[  264.665889] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[  264.666037] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[  265.069837] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  265.070265] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  273.670132] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  273.689401] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  273.772564] wlan0: authenticated
[  273.773146] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  273.806512] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=7)
[  273.806609] wlan0: associated
[  273.806622] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  280.547327] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 15)
[  283.335176] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
[  283.354485] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  283.440054] wlan0: authenticated
[  283.442207] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
[  283.481160] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=7)
[  283.481254] wlan0: associated
[  289.794112] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC address removed> (Reason: 15)

****************** done ******************
```

Comment: Have you tried changing channels -- could be interference.  You are seeing the nearby wireless accesspoints, so may not be a driver problem.  Also check the router protocols like TKIP, and or AES (CCMP) and WPA2 personal settings.

Comment: Wow. I changed the channel on the router and now the wireless works. Thanks @ubfan1, I didn't even consider that it would be something that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll copy the comment down here so you can mark it solved.
Have you tried changing channels -- could be interference. You are seeing the nearby wireless accesspoints, so may not be a driver problem. Also check the router protocols like TKIP, and or AES (CCMP) and WPA2 personal settings.